# specific combinations from a list

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
l1=['a','b','c','a','b']
```

I have to get all combinations but in the given sequence like `abc` the `bca` the `cab`, no combination can skip a given value and make combination with next value like `aca` - skipped `b`.

I have tried `itertools.combination` but it also give a combination such as `['a','c','b']`
which are not desired output

I expect the output to be:

```
[['a'],['b'],['c'],['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','a'],['a','b'],['a','b','c'],['b','c','a'],['c','a','b'],['a','b','c','a'],['b','c','a','b'],['a','b','c','a','b']]
```

Comment: Provide the code of what you have tried, and what didn't work, so we can add suggestions to it

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom code for this.

```
s = []
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
for i in range(len(l)):
    j, k = 0, i+1
    while k <= len(l):
        sub_list = l[j:k]
        if sub_list not in s:
            s.append(sub_list)
        j += 1
        k += 1
print(s)
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']]
```